Block style variations not enqueued for blocks inside HTML code dynamically rendered via JS
The new WP 6.6 will let anyone style any registered block style variations in theme.json via the styles.blocks.blockName.variations property. Check the following post for more info:
https://developer.wordpress.org/news/2024/06/21/styling-sections-nested-elements-and-more-with-block-style-variations-in-wordpress-6-6/
I'm testing this new feature with WP 6.6 RC1 and I have an issue with a custom block I developed some time ago.
My custom block loads a frontend script that retrieves posts via a XMLHttpRequest call (some code omitted for brevity):
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var html = '';
    var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
    var posts = result.posts;
    var numposts = result.numposts;
    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        var post = posts[i];
        html += '<article id="post-' + post.ID + '" class="wp-block-infinite-posts__post">';
        html += '<h2 class="wp-block-infinite-posts__post-title">' + post.post_title + '</h2>';
        html += '<div class="wp-block-infinite-posts__post-content">' + post.post_content + '</div>';
        html += '</article>';
    }
    document.querySelector('.wp-block-infinite-posts .infinite-posts').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
            
});
req.open('GET', rsilp_params_rest.rest_url + 'rsilp/v1/posts/');
req.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', rsilp_params_rest.rest_nonce)
req.send();

I've registered a quote block style variation named big-text-quote in PHP:
function register_block_style_variations() {
    register_block_style(
        'core/quote',
        array(
            'name'  => 'big-text-quote',
            'label' => __( 'Big Text Quote', 'textdomain' ),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_block_style_variations' );

I've styled this new variation via the styles.blocks.blockName.variations in my theme.json:
"styles": {
    "blocks": {
        "core/quote": {
            "variations": {
                "big-text-quote": {
                    "typography": {
                        "fontFamily": "\"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                        "fontSize": "45px",
                        "fontWeight": "700",
                        "fontStyle": "normal",
                        "lineHeight": "1",
                        "textAlign": "initial",
                        "letterSpacing": "-1px"
                    },
                    "border": {
                        "width": "0",
                        "style": "none"
                    },
                    "color": {
                        "background": "transparent",
                        "text": "#000000"
                    },
                    "spacing": {
                        "margin": {
                            "top": "0",
                            "right": "auto",
                            "bottom": "0.5em",
                            "left": "auto"
                        },
                        "padding": {
                            "top": "0",
                            "right": "0",
                            "bottom": "0",
                            "left": "0"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This custom style variation is added to the style selector in the quote block correctly. I can select it with no problems, and the CSS class is-style-big-text-quote--#### is applied to the block and is styled accordingly:
:root :where(.wp-block-quote.is-style-big-text-quote--cb76747d26b42f72e44a0e8d5cc52573) {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: initial;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

Except when a quote block is found in a dynamically retrieved post via the frontend script I posted above.
Part of the generated HTML code by the frontend script:
...
<div class="wp-block-infinite-posts__post-content">
    <blockquote class="wp-block-quote is-style-big-text-quote has-white-color has-black-background-color has-text-color has-background is-layout-flow wp-block-quote-is-layout-flow is-style-big-text-quote--cb76747d26b42f72e44a0e8d5cc52573">
        <p>When I am attacked by gloomy thoughts, nothing helps me so much as running to my books. They quickly absorb me and banish the clouds from my mind.</p>
        <cite>Montaigne</cite>
    </blockquote>
</div>
...

Apparently, WordPress only outputs block variation styles when the corresponding block is actually present on the rendered page. Since the posts in my custom block are fetched dynamically via JavaScript, WordPress cannot determine if the block is present on the page. How can I ensure that the necessary block variation styles for my custom block are always included, regardless of whether the block is detected by WordPress?

have you raised this as a bug? release candidates aren't final versions and problems can still be found and trigger delays or new release candidates to fix things. I would note though that the practice of var html = 'static string' + dynamicdata is extremely insecure. We're also missing the markup that is in the post content, it's described but never shared so we can inspect directly. It's also very possible that the global styles engine didn't include the style variation because it doesn't appear on that page but your JS then pulls it in after the fact.

Also, you mention you can see a CSS selector in the dev tools, but this contradicts the question implying the variation works and styling is applied. When you mentioned this were you talking about inside the block editor? Or are you talking about the frontend? You also mention various #### on the end but never explain where that is or where it comes from, can you ellaborate?

The styling is applied when editing the post containing a quote block in the block editor and in the frontend when viewing the individual post. It's not applied when the post is shown inside my custom block (that renders a series of posts retrieved via a XMLHttpRequest call).

I updated my question with the markup inside the post.post_content var.

The is-style-big-text-quote--cb76747d26b42f72e44a0e8d5cc52573 classname is generated by WP (it's a different string in every new page render)

I think I've identified the issue. WordPress only outputs block variation styles when the corresponding block is actually present on the rendered page. Since the posts in my custom block are fetched dynamically via JavaScript, WordPress cannot determine if the block is present on the page.

take a look at the block interactivity API it might hold the answer to working around that, though it may also do that by demonstrating how to do infinite scrolling
